# Woocommerce shop page redirects to cart

Tags: wordpress, function, woocommerce

On my website http://www.meetingcentre.nl/cart/ I have installed the woocommerce plugin.

When I'm logged in, the 'shop' page works fine. However when I'm not logged in and I will go to the 'shop' page, it redirects automatically to the 'cart' page. Even the 'back to shop' button on the 'cart' page redirects to the 'cart' page.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Shop page: http://www.meetingcentre.nl/reserveren/

Thank you!

Regards, Jer

Comment: Please post code so people can better help you. Thanks!

Comment: looks like a 301 redirect.  Your shop menu links to http://www.meetingcentre.nl/reserveren/ but redirect to http://www.meetingcentre.nl/cart.  You probably have a page redirect plugin installed that is set to redirect logged in and loggged out users to different pages.  Check your plugins.